# Having trouble interpreting this statistics problem?

Tags: probability, statistics

This problem seems simple enough but I can't seem to find a satisfactory answer.

If $P(\text{A}) = .3$ and $P(\text{A} \cap \text{B}) = .25$, what are the possible values of $P(\text{B})$? 
At first I thought $.25/.3$ would be the answer, but my professor pointed out that I do not know if the two events are independent or not. He said look at the general addition rule, but I don't know how to find $P(\text{A}\cup\text{B})$, so I'm not sure how that will help.

Comment: Can you determine $P(A - B)$?

Comment: What does that represent? @N.F.Taussig

Comment: $A - B$ or $A\backslash B$ is the set of elements in $A$ that are not in $B$.

Comment: What I was getting at is that since $P(A - B) = P(A) - P(A \cap B) = 0.3 - 0.25 = 0.05$, an upper bound for $P(B)$ is $1 - 0.05 = 0.95$.  Since $P(A \cap B) = 0.25$, $P(B) \geq 0.25$.

Comment: I understand now, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have
$$\Pr(A\cup B)=\Pr(A)+\Pr(B)-\Pr(A\cap B).$$
The left-hand side must be $\le 1$. It follows that $\Pr(B)\le 0.95$.

It is not hard to check, say with a Venn diagram, that $\Pr(B)=0.95$ is indeed achievable.

For a lower bound, note that $\Pr(B)\ge \Pr(A\cap B)$. So we must have $\Pr(B)\ge 0.25$. By drawing a Venn diagram, we can verify that $\Pr(B)=0.25$ is possible. Just make the event $B$ a subset of $A$.

By drawing an appropriate Venn diagram, we can now show that for any number $k$ between $0.25$ and $0.95$, $\Pr(B)=k$ is achievable,